# finding timeseries in prometheus that have the most labels

Tags: label, prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

Prometheus recommends not using too many labels for timeseries and VictoriaMetrics is even dropping labels if you have more than 30.

But how can I find timeseries that have too many / more than a certain amount of labels?
Is that even possible with PromQL?

Comment: BTW, VictoriaMetrics exports metrics with the number of dropped labels since v1.37.1 - see https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/565

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to measure the number of labels in metrics.

The issue is not the number of labels but the [cardinality of the metric](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels). Even if you have 10 labels and 3 of them are constant (`__name__`, `job`, `instance`) and if the 7 others have 2 values each, you reach a cardinality of 128 for a single metric which is already the limit as rule of thumb.

Therefore, it is not something decided a posteriori or monitored but rather decided at design time: the right number of labels is as few as possible.

Comment: Well, if VictoriaMetrics silently drops labels I need to know how much and which ones.
I ended up writing a script getting all metrics from the api and get all timeseries for that metric name and count the number of labels.